Сборка проекта под Windows 32 в RAD C++ Builder
У меня есть проект на C++, написанный в RAD C++ Builder 11. Я пытаюсь его собрать под Windows x86, и при этом, чтобы он запускался на Windows XP, так как есть необходимость (обновить нет возможности). Проект вроде как собирается по 32 бита, но при запуске приложения выходит ошибка "не является приложением win32". Какие настройки сборки проекта нужно выставить, чтобы проект мог работать на Windows XP и выше?

Посмотрите здесь и тут - может, получится

@MBo  обе ссылки для Delphi, они как то могут ли помочь C++?

Видимо никакие, так как последняя версия с поддержкой Windows XP была XE5, вышедшая более 10 лет назад. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page

Среда (IDE)  ведь одна и та же. C билдером ещё заморочки с вариантами компиляторов. С++ Linker->Output->OS version и Subsystem version меняли?  Ещё здесь поройтесь: https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/41-general-help/
